# Voltage controlled versus current controlled Inverter

Tags: power-electronics, inverter

I would like to ask about the voltage and current controlled inverters.

In a current controlled inverter, the control target is the output current and they provide high quality current to the grid.

In a voltage controlled inverter, the controlled target is the output voltage. Thus they can support the grid voltage.

I would like to ask if there is another main difference between these two control methods and should I choose the one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

A current controlled inverter is good for driving low impedance loads (like feeding excess solar energy into the grid)

A voltage controlled inverter is good for feeding isolated loads (like running individual appliances)